# Dynamically adding Angular ui-select to page

Tags: angularjs, ui-select2, angularjs-ng-transclude

I am attempting to add dom element to the page after returning from an ajax request.  The dom element contains ui-select directives, and I am getting this error:

```
Error: error:orphan
Orphan ngTransclude Directive
```

I am adding the content to the page like this:

```
var childDiv = $compile('<div>_contents_</div>')($scope);
parentDiv.append(childDiv);
```

where *-contents-* contains the ui-select directives below:

```
<p>Selected: {{address.selected.formatted_address}}</p>   
<ui-select ng-model="address.selected"
             theme="bootstrap"
             ng-disabled="disabled"
             reset-search-input="false"
             >
      <ui-select-match placeholder="Enter an address...">
          {{$select.selected.formatted_address}}
      </ui-select-match>
      <ui-select-choices repeat="address in addresses track by $index"
                         refresh="refreshAddresses($select.search)"
                         refresh-delay="0">
          <div ng-bind-html="address.formatted_address | highlight: $select.search"></div>
      </ui-select-choices>   
</ui-select>
```

Any ideas on how better to accomplish this?

Comment: why not use `ng-if` or something like that?

Comment: Hope I explained my dilemma well enough.  I'm adding a clone of a div which already exists on the page, containing the ui-select directives.  I wish to copy the html contents of that div, and recompile them in a new scope.

Comment: So, the template div which already existed on the page, and I was using to clone, was already being compiled, and the ng-transclude attribute was being applied to the template.  I instead opted to render the partial content server side, and send back what is a __fresh__ instance of the html.  Another option I could have used would be to include the template div outside the scope of the application, which seemed counter-intuitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure how the page setup is. But you probably can add the selected items into a $scope array and `ng-repeat` over that array.
That way, when you receive the ajax response, you can just `.push` the item into that array, and `ng-repeat` will take care of adding it to the DOM and creating a child scope.

Comment: Thanks, that would do the trick.  Unfortunately, I'm porting old code to angular, and just want to wrap it in a directive for the time being, and the list is not being generated by ng-repeat.